# Unable to Connect to tcp://magento.hz-gn.com:80. Error #110: Connection timed out

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, admin-panel

Can't open admin panel of magento, I've installed local-de language and an extension for Wordpress, can any one help on this please.

**There has been an error processing your request**

Unable to Connect to tcp://magento.hz-gn.com:80. Error #110: Connection timed out

***Trace:***

```
#0 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/lib/Zend/Http/Client.php(1065): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect('magento.hz-gn.c...', 80, false)
#1 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/local/Hzgn/All/Model/Feed/Extensions.php(88): Zend_Http_Client->request('HEAD')
#2 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Hzgn_All_Model_Feed_Extensions->checkExtensions(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Hzgn_All_Model_Feed_Extensions), 'checkExtensions', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#6 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#8 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/applivecalc/public_html/smykkebazar/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical "phone home" extension.
The module `Hzgn_All` is making a call to a server to probably check your extension licence (and who knows what else).
Their server does not respond, your website is down.
You need to disable the extension from `app/etc/modules/Hzgn_All.xml`. Set the tag `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`.
While you're at it you can also disable the other extension from `Hzgn_All`.
even the extension might do something you need, you are better of without them since this can happen anytime.

Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: there is new problem now I can not open the magento connect manager, it shows a blank page and http://mysite/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A81%2Fsmykke%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F